# HTTP POSTusing sockets - python

Tags: python, sockets, http, post

Ive made a single POST request using sockets in python and it worked fine, but since trying to iterate username and passwords it just is not working, i have been trying for hours if not all day trying to figure out what is the problem.

...i just don't get this at all, code will be below(have tried many different versions of what i have now). Thanks, would really love to know were i have gone wrong with this, i do not think i am too far off?

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#-*- coding: utf8 -*-

#imports
import socket



users = ['bill','ted','sally','sue']

num_00_09 = ['00','01','02','03','04','05','06','07','08','09']
num_10_100 = [x for x in range(10,101)]
pwd = num_00_09 + num_10_100

for user in users:
    for x in range(1,101):
        length = len(str(user)) + len(str(pwd[x]))

        req = '''POST /python/login2r.php HTTP/1.1
        Host: ad.samsclass.info
        User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:61.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/61.0
        Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
        Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
        Accept-Encoding: deflate
        Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        Content-Length: %s''' % (length)

        req1 = '''\nCookie: __cfduid=d97d8c22217a6727cbe1a7d222f5f27ec1531510998
        DNT: 1
        Connection: keep-alive
        Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1

        u=%s&p=%s''' % (user,pwd[x])

        s = socket.socket()
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(2)

        s.connect(('ad.samsclass.info',80))
        s.send(bytes(req + req1,'utf8'))
        r = s.recv(1024)
        print(r.decode('utf8'))
        s.close()
```

And here is the error code(obviously there is this code for each post iteration done)

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sun, 15 Jul 2018 22:41:36 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 313
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at attack.samsclass.info Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

have added +5 too length variable but am now getting another error

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Date: Sun, 15 Jul 2018 22:56:49 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Content-Length: 313
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>400 Bad Request</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Bad Request</h1>
<p>Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.<br />
</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at attack.samsclass.info Port 80</address>
</body></html>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "file02.py", line 42, in <module>
    s.send(bytes(req + req1,'utf8'))
OSError: [WinError 10038] An operation was attempted on something that is not a socket
```

Comment: Like this you will send the request a) with spaces before all header lines except the first one and b) depending on your OS with `\n` instead of `\r\n` line breaks.

Comment: Oh yes sorry, i forgot that i had it on earlier versions, ive been trying this all day it feels like, brain is going fuzzy. I just added + 5 to length and i get another error now

Comment: @nc: you'll get many errors more still. Perhaps it is time to take a break and come back to this tomorrow?

Comment: That new error is not due to you adding 5 to the content length, I'm sure.

Comment: ha yea i know that i was just hoping someone might of been able to tell me what was wrong with my code, feels like ive been going around in circles...you rite im going to take a break also :)

Comment: i had it working earlier but would only work with pwd in range 10-20 if i change pwd to use 00-10 id gave error...and so i changed things again and again and again...:(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your content length is incorrect. Your POST body is longer than you claim it to be:

```
length = len(str(user)) + len(str(pwd[x]))
```

That only counts the user and password string lengths, but your content body consists of more characters still:

```
u=%s&p=%s
```

The `u=` and `&p=` characters *also are part of the POST body*, so your content length is *at least* 5 bytes longer than you told the server to expect.

Next, you are sending headers with a lot of leading whitespace. The indentation on the `req = '''...'''` and  `req1 = '''...'''` strings *is part of the string value*, but HTTP headers should be sent without indentation. Remove that whitespace.

Next, HTTP requires that you send headers with both a carriage return *and* a newline between them. You are sending just `\n` separators, not `\r\n` separators.

You'd be much better off using the [`http.client` library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/http.client.html) that comes with Python. At the very least, try to [study it's source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.7/Lib/http/client.py) so you can learn what that library does, if you must try to do this the hard way with a socket.

If you don't need to go this low-level, just install [`requests`](https://requests.readthedocs.io/) and let it do all the heavy lifting.

Comment: Ok thank you i appreciate your post, i think i need to take a break from this too as i really don't think that's has helped to be honest, yes i know the requests would be better and easier i just wanted to do it in sockets and learn something new :)